# Functions - Sketching and finding $g(x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to see how to go about this problem for my revision.

> **Question 16**
>
> $(a)$ If $g(x)=1-3x$, find $g(x-1)$ in terms of $x$
>
> $(b)$ On the axes below sketch the graph of $g(x)$ and $g(x-1)$

I have a test coming up but I can't remember how you substitute in. I'd appreciate any methods. [I've attempted the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcp9f.jpg) but I can't go further all help appreciated.

Comment: Next time use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical symbols

Comment: There is nothing to remember. If a function is defined by $f(x)=$"a whole lot of stuff with one or more $x$", and you want to know what is $f(2000)$ or $f(x+2)$, then you find every $x$ on the right side of the equation and you replace it with 2000 or $x+2$. A good way to help yourself is by asking "What is $f(0)$? What is $f(3)$? What is $f(1001)$? What is $f(a)$? What is $f(whatever)$?" The answers you give to these questions should help you finish the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If $$g(x) = 1-3x,$$ then $$g(x-1) = 1 - 3(x-1) = 1-3x + 3 = 4-3x.$$  You just replace the $x$ in the original equation with $x-1$.  The graph will look the same as the original graph but shifted $1$ unit to the right.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Are you familiar with parent functions and shifting them?
Given $f(x)$, $f(x-a)$ will always be a translation $a$ units to the right.

You know how to graph $g(x)$, so translate that $1$ unit to the right to find $g(x-1)$.

Note that if $a$ is negative, then it will be a shift $|a|$ to the left.

Comment: Yes. I'm not very good with remembering those :)

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) := g(x-1)$ has the values of $g(x)$, but at $x+1$ each:
$$
f(x + 1) = g((x+1) -1) = g(x)
$$
So the graph of $f$ (red) is the graph of $g$ (green), but one unit shifted to the right:

[image]